# Ruby on Rails filter out with constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have two models, one is User and one is Story. Both models has has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with each other. One user can have many stories and one story can have many users.

Since most of you already have understood, there exists a join table between the two, "users_stories" which has 'user_id' and 'story_id' as its columns.

Question is "How to get the users who do not have story?". Any efficient way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.joins('left join user_stories ON users.id = user_stories.user_id').where('user_stories.user_id is NULL')
```

For more details you can see this image:

https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Answer (score 1):

you can put a scope on model with joins query to check for count of stores greater than zero

```
without_stories_user = User.joins(users_stories: :story).group('users.id').having("count(stories.id) > ?",0)
```

For me this was users without notifications with simillar has_many and belongs to association.

```
without_notifications_user = User.joins(user_notifications: :notification).group('users.id').having("count(notifications.id) > ?",0)
```

Thanks